# how to fix react-native-barcode-builder barcode blank

Tags: react-native, barcode

My react-native barcode only shows black full black bar.

I have done `npm install react-native-svg --save && react-native link react-native-svg`

below is my code

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import Barcode from 'react-native-barcode-builder';

export default class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          React Native Barcode Builder
        </Text>
        <Barcode value="Hello World" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I hope I can get normal barcode instead of full black

Comment: i have put my sample in https://snack.expo.io/S1E0Gbd64, it strange if i change on the fly "hello world" to other words and let the react reload, it somehow show the barcode, but i dunno how to make it proper from beginning

Answer (score 0):

Set the background color to white like this:

```
<Barcode value="Hello World" background="#ffffff" format="CODE128" />
```